# how to set a new property on given object?

Tags: javascript

Given an object, and a key, "addProperty" sets a new property on the given object with a value of true.

```
var myObj = {};
addProperty(myObj, 'myProperty');
console.log(myObj.myProperty); // --> true
```

this is my code, but it's wrong:

```
function addProperty(obj, key) {
  // your code here
  obj.key = key;
    obj.values = true;
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: You aren't giving your object the property `myProperty`, your adding the properties `key` and `value`.

Comment: `obj[key] = true;`

Answer (score -1):

Update your function to this:

```
function addProperty(obj, key) {
    obj[key] = true;
    return obj;
}
```